# Can I launch VNC Viewer for Google Chrome webapp from my web page?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app, vnc, vnc-viewer

I am building a web service that gives VNC connections to remote machines. Currently I am using a project called novnc to embed the VNC inside a  element in my web page. However, it is very slow, especially web browsers, eclipse etc.
When I tried the VNC Viewer for Google Chrome webapp released by novnc, however, it seems really fast. This might be because its running native (native VNC clients are also very snappy).
I was wondering whether I can have my users install the Real VNC webapp, but then invoke it from my webpage with the parameters (host, port etc) that I have specified?
Basically, my webpage takes care of the management of these VMs (saving, creating, cloning etc), and I would like a fast implementation of VNC underneath which I can call from inside the browser (from my webpage). From the different ones I've looked into, this web app seems the fastest, but I don't know if/how I can invoke it with my given params.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but have a look at the native messaging API and the web messaging API. They're both documented in https://developer.chrome.com/apps/messaging.

Answer (score 3):

This bit of code from http://rogierg.blogspot.com/2007/03/run-vnc-and-rdp-from-hyperlinks.html may be helpful to you.

> edit the following text to point to your VNC and save as
>   C:\Windows\VNC.js:

```
 var destination=(WScript.Arguments(0))
 var search='vnc://'
 //Modify the path to VNC Viewer!
 var vncexe='D:\\Apps\\VNC\\vncviewer.exe'
 //WScript.Echo(destination)
 destination=destination.replace(search, '')
 destination=destination.replace('/', '')
 var ws = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell")
 //WScript.Echo(vncexe + " " + destination)
 ws.Exec(vncexe + " " + destination)
```

> Save the next piece of text as VNC.reg and doubleclick:

```
 Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
 [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\vnc]
 @="URL:VNC Connection"
 "URL Protocol"=""
 [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\vnc\DefaultIcon]
 @="C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\mstsc.exe"
 [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\vnc\shell]
 [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\vnc\shell\open]
 [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\vnc\shell\open\command]
 @="wscript.exe C:\\WINDOWS\\vnc.js %1"
```