# Open Chrome VNC Viewer from URL

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, vnc, vnc-viewer

my question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21614377/can-i-launch-vnc-viewer-for-google-chrome-webapp-from-my-web-page) - still unresolved - question.

I would like to be able to open Chrome VNC Viewer apps from a link on a website. I know that chrome supports  [url_handler](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/url_handlers) but I have not found any clue anywhere on how to format the url for Chrome VNC Viewer. Maybe this feature  is not supported?

Does anyone have any clue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about [this official Chrome App](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vnc%C2%AE-viewer-for-google-ch/iabmpiboiopbgfabjmgeedhcmjenhbla), then it's not possible.

Its event page (the only thing that can listen to messages of any kind) is dead simple and can't react to anything but launching the app by the user.

And its manifest does not expose any URL or protocol hanlders.

Comment: Yes I'm talking about that. It's a pity! Maybe it could be useful issue a "feature request"

Comment: Maybe, but Chrome apps don't support arbitrary protocol handling (though maybe it's possible to register `web+vnc:`). And you can't message a Chrome app from a website unless it's specifically whitelisted by the app.

Comment: Damn! And I was thinking to finally have found a quick solution to open automatically a VNC session from a link... Now I'm sitll at square zero.

Comment: Can you assume that the VNC client (not the Chrome app) is installed?

Comment: Mmm... yes I can assume that